# Previous component doesn't vanish after navigation method execution

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, .net-core

Previous component doesn't vanish after navigation method execution. My new component appears in the bottom of old component. What should I do to display new navigated component alone? When I redirect straight to new component *blank view* is displayed. To generate component I used `ng g c componentName`.

**Navigation:**

```
this.router.navigate(['dashboard'], {relativeTo: this.route});
```

**New component:**

```
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

**Router:**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path : "dashboard", component : DashboardComponent},
  {path : "**", component: PageNotFoundComponent}]

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'})],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {  }
export const routingComponents =[DashboardComponent, PageNotFoundComponent]
```

**Project structure:**

[image]

**Template**

```html
<div class="bg">
  <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
          <div class='col-md-3'></div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="login-box well">
                          <legend>Sign In</legend>
                          <div class="form-group">
                              <input id="username-email" placeholder="E-mail or Username" type="text" [(ngModel)]="username" class="form-control" />
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group">
                              <input id="password" placeholder="Password" type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="password"/>
                          </div>
                          <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="checkbox">
                              <label>
                                <input id="login-remember" type="checkbox" name="remember"  [(ngModel)]="remember"> Remember me
                              </label>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group">
                              <input (click)="loginButtonClick()" id="login_button" class="btn btn-default btn-login-submit btn-block m-t-md" value="Login" />
                          </div>
                          <span class='text-center'><a href="/resetting/request" class="text-sm">Forgot Password?</a></span>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class='col-md-3'></div>
      </div>
  </div>

  <router-outlet>
    
  </router-outlet>

  <footer class="fixed-bottom">

      <!-- Copyright -->
      <div class="footer-copyright text-center py-3">© 2018 Copyright:
        <a href=""> worko.com</a>
      </div>
      <!-- Copyright -->
    
    </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post the template code and the router config as well. There could be some issue with the placement of your `router-outlet`

Comment: ok. i already added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the information that you've provided so far, it looks like you've been trying to navigate from the sign in page to the dashboard.

You're still able to see the Login Page fields along with the Dashboard content at the bottom.

And this makes sense since the Router is going to load the contents of the Dashboard Component in the view in the `router-outlet`. But your Login Component is not a part of a Component that's loaded on the `router-outlet`.

In such a case, you would create a LoginComponent` with the following content:

```
<div class="bg">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class='col-md-3'></div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="login-box well">
          <legend>Sign In</legend>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input id="username-email" placeholder="E-mail or Username" type="text" [(ngModel)]="username" class="form-control" />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input id="password" placeholder="Password" type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="password" />
          </div>
          <div class="input-group">
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                <input id="login-remember" type="checkbox" name="remember"  [(ngModel)]="remember"> Remember me
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input (click)="loginButtonClick()" id="login_button" class="btn btn-default btn-login-submit btn-block m-t-md" value="Login" />
          </div>
          <span class='text-center'><a href="/resetting/request" class="text-sm">Forgot Password?</a></span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='col-md-3'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And your RouterConfig will then look something like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [{
    path: "dashboard",
    component: DashboardComponent,
    canActivate: [CanActivateDashboard], // This is a guard that you'll have to add
  },
  {
    path: "login",
    component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
    path: "**",
    component: PageNotFoundComponent
  }
]

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
    onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'
  })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
export const routingComponents = [DashboardComponent, PageNotFoundComponent]
```

By default, you'll load the `/login` route through which, your user will see the contents of the LoginComponent in the View. Since this will now be loaded using Router, and the contents will be loaded on the `<router-outlet>`, only the `DashboardComponent` contents will be loaded on the `<router-outlet>` once the user is navigated to `/dashboard` route.

> PS: Note that the unauthorized user should not be able to directly navigate to `/dashboard`. So you will also have to create a `Guard` in order to prevent that.